# Replacing Filename characters with python

Tags: python, replace, filenames

I have some code which adds the word "_manual" onto the end of a load of filenames.. 
I need to change the script so that it deletes the last two letters of the filename (ES) and then replaces it with _ES_Manual
for example: AC-5400ES.txt --> AC-5400_ES_manual.txt

How would i incorporate that function into this code?

```
folder = r"C:/Documents and Settings/DuffA/Bureaublad/test"
import os # glob is unnecessary
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(fullpath) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero, fileext = filename_split
        print fullpath, filename_zero + "_manual" + fileext
        os.rename(fullpath, filename_zero + "_manual" + fileext)
```

Comment: what is the problem with the existing script ???

Comment: i meant ES sorry! There is no problem with the script - but i need to incorperate replacing the ES currently in the filename into it! sorry if that is confusing!

Comment: You should be able to get this on your own, so here is a hint. Use python's [slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation).

Comment: @Alice Duff I find your present code heavy: you don't need to define objects **fullpath** and **filename_split** and **filename_zero** and **fileext**: it spoils the readability

Comment: Sorry about the readability! Im too scared to delete anything incase it goes wrong..

Comment: @Alice Duff You must not test such a program on real directories. You must create a special directory in which you'll do all the tests in order to preserve all other directories from a severe problem. If you write ``os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename) , ....)`` in which **root** is this special directory or one of its subdirectories, you can't delete files elsewhere than in the special dir. If you remain so shy, you won't go very far in programming

Comment: Ok thank you i will make sure to do that next time! Once i understand stuff a bit more i am sure i will become less shy with deleting stuff!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
pathiter = (os.path.join(root, filename)
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(folder)
    for filename in filenames
)
for path in pathiter:
    newname =  path.replace('ES.txt', '_ES_manual.txt')
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path,newname)
```

Comment: @Alice Duff _hughdbrown_'s code applies only for filenames ending with 'ES.txt' . It is correct if you want to change only these filenames. My code is more generic, it changes all filenames at their 2 last letters before extension. It may happen that it's not what you want, so you could upvote _hughdbrown_. But you can also consider to add a condition in my code to select filenames to change, hence my code is more general and adaptable. You have to consider and to choose.

Answer (score 8):

For a more generalized take on hughdbrown's answer. This code can be used to remove any particular character or set of characters.

```
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk('C:\FolderName')
        for filename in filenames)

for path in paths:
    # the '#' in the example below will be replaced by the '-' in the filenames in the directory
    newname = path.replace('#', '-')
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

Comment: Thanks @nicholas. Quick noobie question but what is paths = (...)? what is it doing? i understand is some kind of iteration command but I am still confused. What is it called and can you point me to something that explains it?

Answer (score 3):

you could do:

```
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename) #should display AC-5400ES.txt
    filename = filename.replace("ES.txt","ES_manual.txt")
    print(filename) #should display AC-5400ES_manual.txt
    fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
    os.rename(fullpath, filename)
```

Comment: But i need to keep the beginng part of the filename "AC-5400ES" - would this work for that?

Comment: @Alice Duff: yes, this statement will take the filename string and replace every occurrence of "ES.txt" and replace it with "ES_manual.txt". This is the most basic way to handle what you described. If you need something more sophisticated, please tell us what you precisely want :)

Comment: hmm.. i tried this and everything just stays exactly the same!

Comment: @Alice Duff: i edited my first answer to display my statement within your code. Do the statements `print` display the expected values?

Comment: You mean this: `filename = filename.replace("ES.txt","ES_manual.txt")` The version you offered has no side effects, as Alice's testing revealed.

Comment: this just seems to print everything twice: the output was: ABC21ES.txt ABC21ES.txt

Comment: @hughdbrown: thanks for the correction and +1 for your functional answer

Answer (score 3):

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    to_write = ['root == %s\n' % root]

    for filename in filenames:
        filename_zero, fileext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        newname = "%s_%s_manual%s" % (filename_zero[:-2],filename_zero[-2:],fileext)

        tu = (os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(root, newname))

        to_write.append('%s --> %s\n' % tu)
        os.rename(*tu)

    print '\n'.join(to_write)
```

Comment: @Alice Duff It's charming the snake !  By the way, I use the object **to_write** to delay the print in chunks, so that general execution is faster

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative without using `os.path.join` or `os.walk`:

```
import os

fileLocation = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\DuffA\\Bureaublad\\test\\"
fileList = os.listdir(fileLocation)

for ii in fileList:
    newName = ii.replace('ES','_ES_Manual')
    if newName != ii:
        os.rename(fileLocation+ii,fileLocation+newName)
```